# Determine Assembler version in CMake?

Tags: cmake

We need to determine the version of GNU's AS (GAS) before deciding on what to build and how to build it. Some older GAS's, like the ones distributed with CentOS 5 and OpenBSD 6, can't handle SSE4 and above. We need to disable code paths that utilize SSE4, AES-NI, SHA, AVX and BMI.

Our primary build system is GNU Make, and it [performs the following](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile#L145):

```
HAVE_GAS := $(shell $(CXX) -xc -c /dev/null -Wa,-v -o/dev/null 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler")
ifneq ($(HAVE_GAS),0)
  GAS210_OR_LATER := $(shell $(CXX) -xc -c /dev/null -Wa,-v -o/dev/null 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.[1-9][0-9]|[3-9])")
  GAS217_OR_LATER := $(shell $(CXX) -xc -c /dev/null -Wa,-v -o/dev/null 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.1[7-9]|2\.[2-9]|[3-9])")
  GAS219_OR_LATER := $(shell $(CXX) -xc -c /dev/null -Wa,-v -o/dev/null 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.19|2\.[2-9]|[3-9])")
endif
```

According to Cmake's [Assembler wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Assembler), CMake has basic support for assembly source files. But it does not discuss how to get the assembler's version.

How do we determine the assembler version when using CMake?

Comment: Maybe set a variable to the result of shell command (e.g.) `assembler --version`. [Helpful link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command:execute_process).

Answer (score 1):

I've run some tests and reviewed CMake's assembler detection code. CMake does

- not determine nor set `CMAKE_ASM-ATT_COMPILER_VERSION` (as it would for e.g. `CXX`)
- only set `CMAKE_ASM-ATT_COMPILER_ID`

So I've used your example code and just translated it to CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(AsmTest CXX)

enable_language(ASM-ATT)

if (CMAKE_ASM-ATT_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_ASM-ATT_COMPILER} --version 
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE _gas_version
    )
    if (_gas_version MATCHES "GNU.[Aa]ssembler.*(2\.[1-9][0-9]|[3-9])")
        set(GAS210_OR_LATER 1)
    endif()
endif()
message(STATUS "GAS210_OR_LATER = ${GAS210_OR_LATER}")
```

**Reference**

- [CMake/Assembler](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Assembler)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying to find the assembler version and hardcode a mapping of what assembler versions support which features, wouldn't it be best to just test assembling some minimal code snippet that you know is failing with the older versions?